# react-d3-tree error parsing external JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, d3.js

I've been trying to change inline data (which worked) to external data in a JSON file.

Originally, I had this, which worked:

```
const treeData = [
                   {
                     name: "Parent"
                     attributes: {
                       id: 12345678
                     },
                     children: [
                       {
                         name: "Child"
                         attributes: {
                           id: 12345679
                         },
                       }
                     ]
                   }
                 ]
return(
  <Tree data = {treeData}/>
)
```

So now I have an external JSON file that looks like this：

```
    {
        "name": "Parent",
        "attributes": {
            "id": 12345678,
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Child",
                "attributes": {
                    "id": 12345679,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And in my program:

```
    const[treeData, setTreeData] = useState(undefined)
    const jsonSource = '../../data/tree-data.json'
    /* Used to center the tree on render */
    useEffect(()=> {
      // Some irrelevant code here...

      // Parse JSON data (Relevant)
      return function parseJSONFile(){
        treeUtil.parseJSON(jsonSource).
        then((data) => setTreeData({data}))
        .catch((error)=>console.log(error))
      }
    }, []);

    return(
      <Tree data = {treeData} />
    )
```

Aand it does not work. Error message:
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`
Which makes me confused because it's my first time dealing with JSON. Any insight on this can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a very simple way (No need for extra works you are doing):

```
import treeData from "./tree-data.json"; // Import your json file (Path to your json file)

function App() {
  return <Tree data={treeData} />;
}
```

Your code have many problems including you write your `parseJSONFile` in return of `useEffect`, Also you just defined `parseJSONFile` and you are not calling it, and even you call, it will be executed on component unmount (because you call it on return of `useEffect`), Also initial state of your `treeData` is `undefined` and it's the cause of `TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`.

My codesandbox link (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-dh0q4?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Woah - thanks for the detailed response- it solved my problem!